# Modding a $30 fog machine, driving high power LEDs?

Tags: led, driver, led-driver, high-power

I've recently acquired a $30 fog machine off Amazon that features, next to the obvious fogger, eight high power RGB LEDs, controlled in series via a RF remote. The LEDs are very bright so I assumed that they'd be high power diodes.

As I've done with another fog machine, I want to mod it to support DMX via an Arduino Nano, a MAX485 and a relay that's used to control the motor to pump the fluid into the heater. That's all relatively easy.

The bigger challenge for me is to drive the eight LEDs. They're mounted on an aluminium based single-layer PCB with only the LEDs on the board. All R,G,B connections are wired up in series, only the Vcc for the LEDs is injected at the fourth LED again.

[image: LED board]

I couldn't figure out which LEDs are used here, but I've used a multimeter to measure the voltage that's going across between Vcc and R, G, and B:

Red: 6.2v => 1.55v per LED (string of four)
Green: 10.9v => 2.72v per LED
Blue: 10.9v => 2.72v per LED

Comparing to other high power (3W or 1W) LEDs on the market, that seems reasonable. Ideally, I'd now want to control them seperately, instead of in series - so I'd need to drive 24 channels via PWM. I could use a PWM Port Expander chip that uses I²C/SPI, but my problem is that I don't know what the best way would be to actually drive the channels of the LEDs.

I'm looking for a as-small-as-possible driver IC, such as the [AL1793](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/AL1791_1792_1793_1794.pdf), which supports three constant-current output channels with PWM dimming control. They look fairly nice, but they're input voltage range starts at 6.5v as a minimum. If my LEDs only need 2.7v or even 1.5v per LED, around ~4v would be converted into heat. Considering the thermal design considerations in the datasheet, that would be twice as much as the "Thermal Management Guideline" suggests.

I've also checked out the [BCR421](https://www.mouser.de/datasheet/2/115/BCR420UW6_BCR421UW7-1511721.pdf) which seems to have a smaller voltange range, but only drives one channel, so I'd need 24 of these.

I've taken exact measurements of the LED board and would probably create my own clone of it (already done that in KiCad), and have it manufactured on Alumium too so the board can act as a good heat sink (just like in the original). I'd probably then mount whatever driver chip I need on that board too, right next to the LEDs.

What do you think - could I go with the AL1793, or would they get too hot? If I do my own PCB, I'd also most likely use my own LEDs, such as [this](https://www.media.highlight-led.de/products/documents/pdf/77900130.pdf) one, which are 3W (350mA per channel) LEDs.

Thank you!

Comment: Drop out voltage is only 250mV, so provided you have two voltage rails you could drive lower voltage LEDs. However, usually once you're looking at an amp of current you are beyond the practical range of a linear regulator. This is why linear driven devices tend to stack diodes to get up to higher voltage and lower current.

Comment: The WS2811 chip is often used to control RGB LEDs. I don't know what the max current is. If you care about saving power, look up how to make a buck converter - it's just PWM plus a few more components.

Comment: I'm going to +1 this question. You've done your homework and know your stuff. Plus, you have made me curious about what you are doing (and I'm not clear about that.) Will enjoy reading good answers.

Comment: You don't need as much PWM channels, why don't you just use matrix connection? You could select the anode of a LED, then send 3 PWM signals to it's cathodes, and after 1 PWM period switch to the next LED and so forth. Look up how LED matrices work on persistense-of-vision effect, with a sufficient speed it will be more than fine.

Comment: @user253751 Yea, I got a couple of the WS2811 or WS2812b chips, they're great, but their max current is at around 18.5mA I believe - so nothing relevant. Could probably pair them with the drivers I mentioned in the post though, that way I could earn the neopixel-compatibility and save me a IO expander!

Comment: @sx107 Right, next to using WS2811 chips, that could work. Although I don't really worry about transferring the data, but rather actually driving the LEDs with a required constant current source.